# httpc:request returns :failed_connect when there are several processes running concurrently

Tags: erlang, elixir

`httpc:request` is behaving completely weird.

If I make a single request to a specific domain, it works perfectly. It returns `:ok` and contains the correct headers/body:

```
:httpc.request(:get, {'http://valid-website-here.com', []}, [
  timeout: 999_999,
  connect_timeout: 999_999
], [])
```

However, pretty much the **very same** code, to the **very same URL**, returns `:failed_connect` when it's among several other concurrent process (either `spawn` or `Task.async_stream`).

```
{:failed_connect,
 [{:to_address, {'valid-website-here.com', 80}}, {:inet, [:inet], :nxdomain}]}
```

The weirdest part comes here: when there are just `30-50` process running concurrently (not only to "valid-website-here.com", but to other URL and domains) it still works... **but when I add much more processes, let's say `1,000` concurrently, then it starts give the above message**. From my perspective, it should **NOT** generate a different response for the same call. It's just a matter of concurrency.

Let me put in a nutshell: *`:httpc.request` works for few concurrent process, but when I add many concurrent process like `1,000` it starts returning `failed_connect`*

Would that be also something related to my network, or DNS lookup with so much request? or is that related to the `httpc.request` itself?

Comment: It will be nice to know what kind of system you  ran: processor(s), RAM, OS,  total system load. Also what is your Internet connectivity, and network traffic. Connectivity of 'valid-website-here.com' and the size of web page also may contribute to the problem.

Comment: What exactly does *not ONLY to "valid-website-here.com"* mean? How many requests are you emitting concurrently? Are your calls failing for only that single URL or are all the requests failing?

Comment: Thank Yuri and Milan for the comments and desire to help. Here are the responses: Yuri) My config (from my laptop yet) https://pastebin.com/raw/6N7bC3kq and my connectivity is 300Mb/s. The content is small, something around ~10kb. Milan) Let me put the same thing with different words: let's say I have a list of 1 million websites. Please consider every one is unique.

Comment: Then I request every one and get their content. Pretty much a SINGLE request for each domain. When there are 30-50 processes runinng concurrently, every thing works PERFECTLY. The issue come when I escalate to 1,000 concurrent processes, or even more using Task.async_stream(1_million_websites, MyCrawlerModule, :download_content, []). Was that clear now? Why with 30-50 concurrent processes it works well, but with 1,000 concurrent processes it doesn't? Maybe a DNS/ISP limitation?

Comment: You could try to find out if it is due to an outside factor by sending the request to a locally running dummy webserver (maybe just some example phoenix project). `nxdomain` in the error message could mean that the DNS resolving didn't work, which could be a limitation. Possible that the DNS service doesn't like 1,000 requests from the same IP in a short period of time...

Comment: Thanks for helping, Ole Spaarmann. Yes, I've prepared a dummy local webserver and no errors were thrown even with ~10,000 concurrent requests... I'm guessing as well the DNS server is not happy with that amount of request per second. Uhmm one thing I just though was to pre-cache every IP it self and then make the requests directly to the IP's desired. Does that sound like the best solution for my case? The bottleneck is that I'll constantly need to update the DNS, as they can be changed from time to time.